# How to print 10 perfect numbers from a user given number in C?

Tags: c, perfect-numbers

I can't figure out how to print next ten [Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). 
Here's what I have got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, c = 1, d = 2, sum = 1;
    printf("Enter any number \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The perfect numbers are:");
    while(c <= 10) { 
        sum = 1;
        d = 2;
        while(d <= n / 2) { //perfect no
            if(n % d == 0) {
                sum = sum + d;
            }
            d++;
        }
        if(sum == n) {
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am currently receiving:

```
input: 2 (say)  
output: 6
```

What I want:

```
input: 2  
output:
6  
28  
496  
8128  
33550336  
858986905  
137438691328  
2305843008139952128  
2658455991569831744654692615953842176
191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216
```

I have just started coding. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the output of your current program and the output you would like to achieve.

Comment: I have. Please check.

Comment: You get (32-bit) integer overflow after the sixth entry (858986905 — 9 digits).  Even using 64-bit integers (`unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`) won't handle the eighth (2305843008139952128 with 21 digits).  So, if you're serious about it, you'll need to use a multi-precision (integer) arithmetic package — there are many of them.

Comment: See [OEIS A000396](https://oeis.org/A000396) — 6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, 137438691328, 2305843008139952128, 2658455991569831744654692615953842176, 191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216.

Comment: Note: 191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216 is about  178 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Perfect_numbers), divide and conquer**

Perfect numbers are of the form  2<sup>p − 1</sup> * (2<sup>p</sup> − 1).

Code will need extended precision to form `191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216`

**Increase efficiency**

Iterating to `<= n / 2` takes far too long.  Iterate up to `<= n / d`

```
// while(d <= n / 2) {
while(d <= n / d) {
```

Sample improved code:

```
bool isprime(unsigned long long x) {
  if (x > 3) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    for (unsigned long t = 3; t <= x / t; t += 2) {
      if (x % t == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return x >= 2;
}
```

Advanced: See [Lucas–Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) for quick prime test of Mersenne numbers

---

The below code works for all but the 10th perfect number as code must test for isprime(2<sup>67</sup> - 1) and I should leave something for OP to do.

```
static void buff_mul(char *buff, unsigned power_of_2) {
  unsigned long long m = 1ull << power_of_2;
  size_t len = strlen(buff);
  unsigned long long carry = 0;
  for (size_t i = len; i > 0;) {
    i--;
    unsigned long long sum = (buff[i] - '0') * m + carry;
    buff[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  while (carry) {
    memmove(buff + 1, buff, ++len);
    buff[0] = carry % 10 + '0';
    carry /= 10;
  }
}

void print_perfext(unsigned p) {
  // 2**(p-1) * (2**p - 1)
  assert(p > 1 && p <= 164);
  char buff[200] = "1";
  buff_mul(buff, p);
  buff[strlen(buff) - 1]--; // Decrement, take advantage that the LSDigit is never 0
  buff_mul(buff, p - 1);
  puts(buff);
  fflush(stdout);
}

//unsigned next_prime(unsigned first_numeber_to_test_if_prime) {
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned p = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   // If p prime && 2**p − 1 is prime, then 2**(p − 1) * (2**p − 1) is a perfect number.
    while (!isprime(p) || !isprime((1uLL << p) - 1))
      p++;
    printf("%2u ", p);
    print_perfext(p);
    p++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 2 6
 3 28
 5 496
 7 8128
13 33550336
17 8589869056
19 137438691328
31 2305843008139952128
61 2658455991569831744654692615953842176
```

Answer (score 3):

The integer overflow issue mentioned by several folks is significant, but *secondary*.  Even if we fix your broken logic, and adjust it to handle larger, fixed sized integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long number;
    printf("Enter any number \n");
    scanf("%llu", &number);
    printf("The perfect numbers are:\n");

    int total = 0;

    while (total < 10) { 
        unsigned long long sum = 1, divisor = 2;

        while (divisor <= number / 2) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                sum += divisor;
            }
            divisor++;
        }

        if (sum == number) {
            printf("%llu\n", number);
            total++;
        }

        number += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You still wouldn't get past the first four perfect numbers in any reasonable amount of time:

```
> ./a.out
Enter any number 
2
The perfect numbers are:
6
28
496
8128
```

The *primary* issue is you're using a *bad algorithm*.  Read about [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), and their relationship to perfect numbers, as well as the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test). This approach takes more thought, but surprisingly, not much more code.  And will produce more results faster (though eventually bog down as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the counter after you find a perfect number, so increasing `c` must happen in the `if` statement that checks the perfect number, like this:

```
if(sum==n){
    printf("%d",n);
    c++;
}
```

After this you need to increase the number, called n, like this:

```
n++;
```

and based on the numbers, @Jonathan Leffler is right, you should use proper variables.

Answer (score 1):

From output you wrote I belive that u want to show 10 first perfect numbers
Now u are only showing 6 because u show them from 1 to 10. In this range there is only 6.
I wrote sth like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isperfect(int input) {
int sum = 0, value = input / 2;
do {
    if (input % value == 0) sum += value;
    value--;
} while (value);
if (input == sum) return 1;
else return 0;
}
int main() {
int i;
int count;
for (i = 2, count = 0; count < 4; i++) {
    if (isperfect(i) == 1) {
        count++;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

But I don't recomend counting more than 4 because its gonna take too much time